# Rename and update text in SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, rename, sentence

I need to rename in a SQL content this text:

[youtube]SP05XjJFeoo[/youtube]

in
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP05XjJFeoo[/youtube]

But the problem is that the code "SP05XjJFeoo" can be anything, I need a SQL wildcard in a update sentence.

The data entry is through phpmyadmin.

Comment: Renaming tables on the fly sounds fundamentally wrong.  What is the motivation behind this attempt?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to tables, I meant the content within tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try code something like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = "[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + SELECT SUBSTRING(column1, 9, 100)
```

The SUBSTRING gets the variable part of the column value, so that it can be appended to the new text.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I get this error: 

# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; Manual That Corresponds the check to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUBSTRING (text, 9, 100)' at line 1